# how to get the values of array only if the condition is matched

Tags: numpy

I have two arrays `a&b`,  array `a` is numerical values.   `array([27, 28, 29, 21, 17, 15, 19, 22, 18, 23, 24, 25, 30, 26])` array `b` is categorical vlaues. `b=array(['no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes','yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no'], dtype=object)` . I want to get the values if the condition is `yes`

```py
import numpy as np 
np.where(b =='yes',a,0)
output: array([ 0,  0, 29, 21, 17,  0, 19,  0, 18, 23, 24, 25, 30,  0])
```

I want to get only values if  `yes` matched. I can use `if` condition. but I don't want to.

expected output :

```py
array([29 21 17 19 18 23 24 25 30])
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use boolean indexing:

```
out = a[b=='yes']
```

output:

```
array([29, 21, 17, 19, 18, 23, 24, 25, 30])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using masked array in numpy.

```
out_ma = np.ma.array(a, b[b=="no"])
out_ma.nonzero()
```

Output:

```
array([29, 21, 17, 19, 18, 23, 24, 25, 30])
```